# Filtering all the searches on a model with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im dealing with a situation with a refactor on a running app with Ruby on Rails.

On the app, I have a user that can have their profile active/inactive.

On the User too, I have his date of birth. And for all the users that are less then 13 years old, the accounts need to behavior like "inactive".

I just added a is_active boolean property to the User model.

The question is: I dont want to refactor ALL my queries on Users on the app, adding

```
User.where(is_active: true).where(age > 13)
```

By hand on all the models

I want to use some other technique, maybe a callback function on the User model, or in the controller.

What do you sugest?

Comment: You can make use of `default_scope`. But you may face some problems in the long run so do your research accordingly

Comment: I would suggest to add scope and update everywhere wherever required instead of adding `default_scope` 

https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/ - This article explains why we should avoid `default_scope`

Comment: @SampatBadhe yes, exactly the link i was searching to add in the answer :)

Comment: @fernando-maymone please take the link above in consideration while using default scope

Comment: Honestly while the simple resolutions presented will work you may want to look into authorization policies as a solution. There are libraries like `cancancan` and `pundit` that provide such functionality and from an application perspective are generally far more maintainable than using the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[default_scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope) is what you need if you don't want to change queries already written but want to add the default condition

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(is_active: true).where("age > 13") }
end
```

**NOTE**: `default_scope` is not suggested to use so do your research accordingly

**Solution 2:**

You will have to add the scope once in all the places where you are querying on the users table

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(is_active: true).where("age > 13") }
end
```

and use it

```
User.active.where(...)
```

you might have to handle the above conditions while joining the models